# Store "$@" to a variable for use later, respecting quoted args

Tags: bash

I have a [project written in bash](https://github.com/d11wtq/skittle). One part of the interface requires users to invoke bash functions with a layer of indirection, as so:

```
require some_fun "arg 1" "arg 2"
```

Which executes `some_fun "arg 1" "arg 2"` (and then does some additional things, hence the reason it exists). Currently I'm just invoking `"$@"` to do this and everything works correctly.

I now have a need to *defer* those function calls until later and can't find a way to do this in Bash. Effectively I want to push `"$@"` onto a stack each time `require` is invoked, then loop over that stack and execute the arguments, just like my current behaviour. This would require multidimensional arrays, which bash doesn't support, so I'm trying this:

```
require() {
  dep_num=${#SK_deps[@]}
  dep_var="SK_dep_$dep_num"
  eval $dep_var="$@"
  SK_deps+=($dep_var)
}
```

Which basically generates a variable-variable to store the "$@" and puts the variable name in `$SK_deps`.

I then try to iterate the list with:

```
for dep_var in ${SK_deps[@]}
do
  ${!dep_name}
done
```

But this seems to be breaking the quoted arguments, so:

```
require some_fun "arg 1" "arg 2"
```

Is interpreted as:

```
require some_fun arg 1 arg 2
```

Without the quotes.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? Using "$*" also incurs the loss of quote positioning. It feels like there should be a way to do this in Bash, without hacking around with sed/awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `eval` solution isn't so bad. The key is to leverage `printf`'s **shell-quoted** mechanism, which will handle all the tricky cases for you:

```
require() {
    local quoted
    printf -v quoted ' %q' "$@"
    SK_deps+=("$quoted")
}
```

Then you can run it normally:

```
for dep in "${SK_deps[@]}"; do eval $dep; done
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know this existed. Will try it shortly :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote the array when expanding it:

```
for dep_var in "${SK_deps[@]}"
do
  ${!dep_name}
done
```

Also the following line seems suspicious:

```
eval $dep_var="$@"
```

Try running your script with `set -xv` to see how variables are really expanded.

Comment: `$SK_deps` is just an array of variable *names*, not the args themselves. It is just populated with strings like `SK_dep_0` and `SK_dep_5` ;)

Comment: I think I have worked out a solution (at least in my head) that stores `$#` and `$1, $2, ... $n` separately.

Comment: Yeah, I've been outputting the expansion and it is definitely missing the quotes. I also tries `eval $dep_var=\"$@\"` so that the quotes were in the eval, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really ugly solution using eval, so any better suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
require() {
  local tmp_var=""
  for arg in "$@"
  do
    tmp_var="$tmp_var \"$arg\""
  done
  SK_deps+=("$tmp_var")
}
```

Then:

```
for dep in "${SK_deps[@]}"
do
  eval $dep
done
```

It's clear using eval like this is fraught with edge-cases such as quotes already in the args, or backslashes already in the args, etc.